# How does this C code work?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

What is `a##b` & `#a`?

```
  #define f(a,b) a##b
  #define g(a)   #a
  #define h(a) g(a)

  main()
  {
          printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));  //how should I interpret this?? [line 1]
          printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));  //and this? [line 2]
  }
```

**How does this program work?**

---

The output is

```
12
f(1, 2)
```

---

now I understand how `a##b` & `#a` work. ***But why is the result different in the two cases (line 1 and line 2)?***

Comment: What happens when you run that program? Doing that should help you understand what is happening.

Comment: Really, playing a while with that code will shed light. And if you have specific questions fell free to ask them here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ## concatenates two tokens together. It can only be used in the preprocessor.

`f(1,2)` becomes `1 ## 2` becomes `12`.

The # operator by itself *stringifies* tokens: `#a` becomes `"a"`. Therefore, `g(f(1,2))` becomes `"f(1,2)"` when the preprocessor is done with it.

`h(f(1,2))` is effectively `#(1 ## 2)` which becomes `#12` which becomes `"12"` as the preprocessor runs over it.

Answer (score 5):

For questions like these (and also more "real-world" problems having to do with the preprocessor), I find it very helpful to actually read the code, *after* it has been preprocessed.

How to do this varies with the compiler, but with gcc, you would use this:

```
$ gcc -E test.c

(snip)
main()
{
        printf("%s\n","12");
        printf("%s\n","f(1,2)");
}
```

So, you can see that the symbols have been both concatenated, and turned into a string.

Comment: why does the second printf end up in `"f(1,2)"` instead of `"12"`?

Comment: @hanifr: Because the g() macro stringifies its argument, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

a##b will paste the code togather.

so f(1,2) will become 12

Comment: That is only half of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The f(a,b) macro concatenates its arguments, g(a) turns its arguments to a string and h(a) is helper macro for g(a).  I think it will output:

```
12
f(1,2)
```

The reason is that the h(a) macro causes its argument to be full expanded before passing it to g(a) while g(a) will take its arguments literally without expanding them first.

Comment: why does the second printf end up in `"f(1,2)"` instead of `"12"`?

Comment: why does this happen: `"The reason is that the h(a) macro causes its argument to be full expanded before passing it to g(a) while g(a) will take its arguments literally without expanding them first."`?

Answer (score 0):

a##b is the string contatenation of the literals a and b, so f(1,2) is "12"

#a is the string literal a, so g(3) is "3"

Answer (score 0):

## is the macro concatenation operator. So for example `f(foo,bar)` would be equivalent to `foobar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #define f(a,b) a##b
  #define g(a)   #a
  #define h(a) g(a)
```

So, ## combine 2 parts directly together, no matter what types they are...
Give you a example..
`printf("%d\n",f(1,2));` you get 12, that means here f(1,2) is 12 a integer.

```
    int a2 = 100;
    printf("%d\n",f(a,2));
```

here f(a,2) is label. it points to a label in your code context, if there is not `int a2 = 100`, you get compile errors.
And `#a` turns whatever a is , into a string...
And then `h(a) g(a)`
It's very strange..
It looks that when you call h(a), it turns to g(a), and passes a into g(a), firstly, it interprets what a is. so, before you can g(a), a is transformed to f(a,b) = a##b = 12