# Why is the output of the following two statements different?

Tags: c, function

code:

```
 #define f(a,b) a##b
 #define g(a)   #a
 #define h(a) g(a)

 main()
 {
      printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));  //[case 1]
      printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));  //[case 2]
 }
```

output:

```
12
f(1, 2)
```

**Why is the output not same in both cases?**

*[I understood the concatenation (`a##b`) and string conversion (`#a`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686324/how-does-this-c-code-work/), but I did not get why the output is different in both cases.]*

Comment: Which compiler platform are you using. I wouldn't be surprised if that behavior is compiler specific.

Comment: I am using `Cygwin gcc` on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant part of the spec is:

6.10.3.1

"After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified,
argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded
by a # or ## preprocessing token or followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is
replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
expanded."

In other words, when macro parameters are replaced, there is a round of macro expansion on the argument first, *unless* the parameter appears with # or ##.

So `g(blah)` just stringifies `blah`. `h(blah)` first macro-expands `blah`, then stringifies it.

The difference is particularly relevant when you want to stringify macro names:

```
printf("The value of the " g(NULL) " macro is " h(NULL));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the order of evaluation. In the first case h and f get evaluated in the first pass to g and 12. The second pass of macro evaluation would then convert that to 12. In the second case, g directly evaluates f(1,2) into a string.

Comment: yes, I understand that. But why does that happen the way you just mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

When a function style macro is expanded, any instances of parameters in the replacement list which aren't preceded by a `#` or immediately adjacent to a `##` are replaced by the corresponding argument after macro expansion. Macro expansion doesn't happen for parameters which follow a `#` or are adjacent to a `##`. If there are any macros left in the expansion then macro expansion happens recursively on the replacement until there are no macros remaining. (The expansion of any macro won't expand itself during its expansion at any level of nesting so you can't get any infinite recursion.)

In your example, `g(f(1,2))` becomes `#` of `f(1,2)` (no expansion of macro argument) which is "f(1, 2)", a string literal.

`h(f(1,2))` becomes `g( 12 )` because `f(1,2)` undergoes macro expansion, there is a remaining macro in this expansion, so this is expanded again and `g( 12 )` becomes "12".

Answer (score 0):

C macros are not functions. It's simple text substitution. Just substitute *a* in g(a) with *"f(1, 2)"* and that's your answer.

Comment: so in `case1`, `h(f(1,2))` becomes `g(f(1,2))`. So, the results should be the same!

Comment: No since parameters after # are not expanded.